# How to wait for cypress command to finish before moving forward

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, integration-testing

I have a custom cypress command which performs some asynchronous tasks, and based on the result of the command I want to perform some assertions

But the problem is the tests that come after calling the command will either run before the command finishes or will have wrong values.

below is my code

**Command**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("testCommand", () => {
    cy.request("http://localhost:3000/testApi").then(({ body }) => {
        cy.request(`http://localhost:3000/testApi${body.query}`).then(() => {
            console.log("success");
        });
    });
});
```

**test**

```js
describe("Summary Page", () => {
    it("my demo test", () => {
        console.log("before command runs");

        cy.testCommand();

        console.log("after command runs");
    });
});
```

**Actual result**

```
before command runs
after command runs
success
```

**Required result**

```
before command runs
success
after command runs
```

as you can see the output `after command runs` will run before the command finished

Is there any way to wait for the command to complete before moving forward with tests

Answer (score 8):

Regardless of whether or not your custom command returns a cypress chain, you can run code *after* the command wrapping it in a `then` callback:

```js
describe('Summary Page', () => {
  it('my demo test', () => {
    console.log('before command runs')
    cy.testCommand()
    cy.then(() => {
      console.log('after command runs')
    })
  })
})
```

As for using `async/await`, Cypress by default does not support async/await, see this [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1417) and the long discussion inside it.

To reduce the number of callback you may try either [cypress-promise](https://github.com/NicholasBoll/cypress-promise) or [cypress-thenify](https://github.com/mbolotov/cypress-thenify) libraries. However, each of them has it's own limitations.

Answer (score 2):

Along with above answers , you can also use wait() and do the synchronous operations

```
describe("Summary Page", () => {

    it("my demo test", () => {
        console.log("before command runs");

        cy.testCommand().as('getCommand');
        cy.wait('@getCommand').then((interception) => {
        console.log("after command runs");
    })  
});
```

Refer to this for more details:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait#Alias

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
  Cypress.Commands.add("testCommand", () => {
    cy.request("http://localhost:3000/testApi").then(({ body }) => {      
      cy.request(
        `http://localhost:3000/testApi${body.query}`
      ).then(() => { console.log("success"); });
    }).as('myRequest')
  
    cy.wait(
      '@myRequest', {timeout:30000}
    ).its('response.statusCode').should('eq', '200')
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the fact that non-cypress commands runs asynchronously meaning it will not necessarily run the commands in sequence in which it is written. To tackle this you can use `then()`, something like:

```js
describe('Summary Page', () => {
  it('my demo test', () => {
    console.log('before command runs')
    cy.testCommand().then(() => {
      console.log('after command runs')
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: hey alapan thanks for quick response .. i have two doubts .. first my command is not chainable so .then is not working on it ... secondly is there any way to not chain like this and use something like await in js

i am new to cypress so don't have much idea about it .. thanks

Comment: Please add the original code in order to give a proper answer. Yes async-await can help in this regard.

Comment: The actual code is a bit complicated that's why I have provided the simplified demo code with almost exact condition as actual code

Comment: It's not that the non-Cypress commands run asynchronously, it's that non-Cypress commands run immediately (before any Cypress commands are executed), but Cypress commands are queued up and run in sequence afterward.

Answer (score 0):

If `console.log()` is not necessary, then you can replace with [`cy.log()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/log), which will log to the test runner. That way you can replace at the exact locations without altering too much of you code.

**Command**

```
Cypress.Commands.add("testCommand", () => {
    cy.request("http://localhost:3000/testApi").then(({ body }) => {
        cy.request(`http://localhost:3000/testApi${body.query}`).then(() => {
            // you may want to add some assertion here, maybe expected status code
            cy.log("success");
        });
    });
});
```

**test**

```
describe("Summary Page", () => {
    it("my demo test", () => {
        cy.log("before command runs");
        cy.testCommand();
        cy.log("after command runs");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the Cypress commands are queued up to be run later, but the non-Cypress commands are run immediately.  Since `console.log` is not a Cypress command, both occurrances of it are run before the Cypress command enqueued by `cy.testCommand()`.

Per the [Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/table-of-contents#Commands):

> Cypress commands don't do anything at the moment they are invoked, but rather enqueue themselves to be run later.

In your case, since you want to run assertions on the result of your command, the appropriate approach to use is probably the [`should`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should) method.

```js
it("my demo test", () => {
    cy.testCommand().should(result => {
        console.log("after command runs");
        // Perform assertions here using the result of the command
    });
});
```